# Xcode install on OSX 10.9 - clang: error: no input files

Tags: gcc, clang

I'm in the process of installing XCode Command Line Tools onto OSX 10.9 Mavericks

I did a successful install XCode:

```
$ xcode-select -p 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

However when I type in either `$ clang` or `$ gcc` it returns:

```
clang: error: no input files
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just type the command without any input files, then as commented, the compiler reports an accurate error message.

But if you have an existing project, then you can see that same "`clang: error: no input files`" message when:

- [you move your folder/files after making the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062519/6309)
- [one of your files isn't recognized by the XCode project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218432/6309)
- [your project pre-compile header settings is wrong](http://www.zeroc.com/forums/help-center/5838-xcode-clang-error-no-input-files-failed-exit-code-1-a.html) (wrong prefix):

  > In Xcode "`Build settings`" reviews the value for "`Prefix header`".
  >   It seems to me that you have it set to "`MySecondTabbApp/MySecondTabbApp-Prefix.pch`" and it should be just "`MySecondTabbApp-Prefix.pch`"

---

The [OP user2925321](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2925321/user2925321) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619710/xcode-install-on-osx-10-9-clang-error-no-input-files/19620036?noredirect=1#comment29174482_19620036):

> The error was that I was running through steps to configure ruby and was directed to instructions on another page that **just stated to check for `$ gcc` instead of `$ gcc --version`**.
>   Obviously new to coding, trying to learn more.

Comment: The error was that I was running through steps to configure ruby and was directed to instructions on another page that just stated to check for $ gcc instead of $ gcc --version. Obviously new to coding, trying to learn more. This was helpful, thanks!

Comment: @user2925321 good feedback, thank you. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

Try `gcc -v`.
I am on a Mac (Mavericks) and that worked for me. It will tell you which version you are using (and you will know it is installed).

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue. Type in `xcode-select --install`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: double check how the file in question is added to the xcode project. In my case, the file was set to "relative to group" instead of "relative to this project" and it was causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

just type gcc -v which will spit an output specifying the prefix flag with which gcc was installed and the LLVM version as well. Specifying gcc on the command line without an option will report the issue you say it is reporting because its not able to find a file to compile using gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error while setting up a React Native project.  [Here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2290) is what worked for me.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```