# not able to install ruby on rails in OSX mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I have OSX mavericks and I was trying to install ruby on rails .First I tried Installing via RailsInstaller (http://railsinstaller.org/en) ,There was a notice in the website saying "Please do not run the installer on OSX Mavericks until further notice."

Then I tried installing using rvm which turned out to be a night mare .

I followed instructions from all the below links none seem to work

[Installing Rails on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580685/installing-rails-on-mavericks)

[Xcode install on OSX 10.9 - clang: error: no input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619710/xcode-install-on-osx-10-9-clang-error-no-input-files)

[Installing Rails on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580685/installing-rails-on-mavericks?lq=1)

http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

I have installed Xcode 5.0 and I have even manually downloaded Command lines tools

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

when I try

```
rails -v
```

I get a message

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
>
> $ sudo gem install rails

Then I tried command for which I got an error message

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing rails:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for libkern/OSAtomic.h... yes creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" compiling atomic_reference.c atomic_reference.c:57:59: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void **' to parameter of type 'volatile int64_t *' (aka 'volatile long long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h:507:93: note: passing argument to parameter '__theValue' here
```

I'm not able to use `xcode-select --install` either which says the software is not present in the server

Please guide on how to install rails on my `osx mavericks` ?

Comment: It doesn't specifically help you solve your problem, but have you tried following [this guide](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html).

Comment: I already tried that guide . I posted the same link in question as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 needs RubyGems 2.0.3. Update it and you should be good to go.

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

Then,

```
gem install rails
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get this error message when I try the above commands aruns-mbp:~ arun$ gem update --system 2.0.3
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
aruns-mbp:~ arun$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: @Arunachalam You're likely using the system-provided Ruby. You can solve that problem with `sudo gem update --system 2.0.3`, but you probably should use something like [RVM](https://rvm.io) to manage your Ruby, if you're going to be doing serious development work.

Comment: my gem version is 2.0.3 and I did try with sudo but same result .I also have rvm installed .