# Pod Update is removing "Target Support Files" but not updating my project settings

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode7

Admittedly, it's been awhile since I've run a pod update on my project.  Today I was trying to do just that, and am running into issues.

After running a 'pod update', the project will not compile.  Here is what I've noticed.  The update itself appears to run fine, just like normal.  I did notice that all the files in 'Pods/Target Support Files` have been removed.

When I attempt to build, I get an error like this one for most of my pods:

```
lang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/logan/development/ProjectNameRemoved/src/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AJNotificationView/Pods-AJNotificationView-dummy.m'
```

`clang: error: no input files`

When I go to the Build Phases for the pods with this error, I can see that the dummy .m file is still in there, even though it doesn't exist:
[image: dummy file]

Removing all of those doesn't seem to help, as then I start getting the following errors:

[image: second error]

Digging down into the target's settings I can see the GCC prefix header is still set to use a nonexistent pch file:

[image: prefix header]

I'm not really sure where to go from here.  It seems like pod update is removing certain files, but my pbxproj is not being updated to correlate these changes.  Do I need to figure out how to do this manually?

I'm currently running XCode7 and CocoaPods 0.38.2

Comment: We never ended up really "solving" our problem.  In the end, we had to start from scratch with CocoaPods.  I used https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate to remove Cocoapods, and then used our old podfile to run a fresh pod install.  We were met with a lot of errors we solved through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539147/xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods and https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2053 . Overall, CocoaPods has consumed more time then it has saved in the past 12 months.  We're going to move forward without it.

Comment: delete pods folder along with pod.lock file then do pod install worked for me

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I encountered this problem when I was refactoring a project. After removing a CocoaPod, I had remnants of it that were referenced. Cleaning caches and rebuilding did not resolve the issue.

I was able to resolve it using [`cocoapods-deintegrate`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) referenced in the user's comment above.

**Steps to resolve:**

1. Close the project in Xcode so you don't have Xcode throwing warnings at you about differences between versions (assuming you're using version control, which is a good idea if you're messing with CocoaPods).
2. Install `cocoapods-deintegrate` by typing in **Terminal**:

   `gem install cocoapods-deintegrate`
3. Type `pod deintegrate` from the directory of your project.
4. Open the project in Xcode, clean caches and rebuild. Your **Podfile** should still be there...**leave it alone**. We'll get to that in a moment.
5. Close the project.
6. Type `pod install`
7. Open the project, clean caches and rebuild.

These are the steps I followed to [resolve this issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA).

**Update:**

I also used this methodology to resolve a linker error which cropped up when I deleted a reference to a class file instead of the file itself. Upon doing that, I got this error:

> error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

Comment: Yeah, that's what we did as well, so I'll give you the accepted answer.  That being said, we've switched to Carthage and never looked back to CocoaPods.

Comment: Nice - these steps also worked for me in React Native.  (The Target Support Files directory was empty when building.)

Comment: Life saver man, I used to resolve my linker errors. I have the same problem after updating my projects cocoapod files, It shows me liker error for the files which was not existing. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: "When I go to the Build Phases for the pods with this error, I can see that the dummy .m file is still in there, even though it doesn't exist: " quoted in question, this was my error.

Comment: @Adrian, I did not get to follow this to the letter but I followed your steps as closely as possible and it worked, I finally got a successful build in `ios` again.

Comment: @Daniel Great to hear. Looking forward to SPM obviating the need for CocoaPods :)

Comment: @Adrian, if I need to change the `targets` to my `Podfile` should I follow your steps above as well? Or does the answer require I officially post as a question?

Comment: Without knowing more about what your Podfile looks like, I'd post as a standalone question. Frankly, if you've really ****ed it up, I'd start over again with a factory fresh Podfile.

Comment: @Adrian, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263793/how-to-properly-update-my-targets-on-podfile?noredirect=1#comment101026597_57263793

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

*You should be located at `Podfile` directory

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if the answer in this post can help?

[Xcode install on OSX 10.9 - clang: error: no input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619710/xcode-install-on-osx-10-9-clang-error-no-input-files)

I would try reconstructing my project.

Comment: I can solve the input files error, it exposes the pre-compiled header error after... Finally if I solve that then the libraries don't work anymore.  Assuming because they're missing the pch.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same thing after re configuring my podfile to accommodate multiple targets.  I was just going to use the suggested answer above, but before doing anything I committed my changes in git.  That solved the problem.  The git commit included lots of file deletions and additions done by cocoapods, so I guess some things were still hanging around.