# apple llvm 5.1 error clang

Tags: ios

while building my app it gives me APPLE LLVM 5.1 error 
The description of error is given below,

```
    ProcessPCH /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix-gwcwubtrxmgndfbvpagazcbdlfnr/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch.pch GoogleAPIParsing/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/ankit/Desktop/Projects/GoogleAPIParsing
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -iquote /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAPIParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIParsing.build/GoogleAPIParsing-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAPIParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIParsing.build/GoogleAPIParsing-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAPIParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIParsing.build/GoogleAPIParsing-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAPIParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIParsing.build/GoogleAPIParsing-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAPIParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIParsing.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAPIParsing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIParsing.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ankit/Documents/FacebookSDK --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix-gwcwubtrxmgndfbvpagazcbdlfnr/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix-gwcwubtrxmgndfbvpagazcbdlfnr/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/ankit/Desktop/Projects/GoogleAPIParsing/GoogleAPIParsing/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch -o /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAPIParsing-blyffdbdszklenaxwqqnwiriiqjr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix-gwcwubtrxmgndfbvpagazcbdlfnr/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch.pch

    GoogleAPIParsing/GoogleAPIParsing-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Will this help you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062475/regarding-xcode-error-clang-error-no-input-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake,

i accidentally deleted my .pch and .plist files and when i added it manually xcode showed me this error , so i had to manually add those files in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your project there are ‘release’ or ‘retain’ and I guess you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) in your Xcode projects, but you haven't change your flags.

I also recommend you to check this link; http://blog.evanmulawski.com/?p=36[image]